# Mocking timedelta.total_seconds()

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, magicmock

Is there any way to mock total_seconds() from the following code?

```
start = datetime.now()
...
end = datetime.now()
diff = (end - start).total_seconds()
```

I've tried it but getting this error

> TypeError: unorderable types: MagicMock() > int()

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Patching datetime.timedelta.total\_seconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45566825/patching-datetime-timedelta-total-seconds)

Answer (score 1):

It is durty example, but it could give some hints:

```
from datetime import datetime
import unittest


def need_test():
    start = datetime.datetime.now()
    end = datetime.datetime.now()
    diff = (end - start).total_seconds()
    return diff


class SimpleTestCase(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        datetime_mock = mock.patch(__name__ + ".datetime")
        self.datetime_mock = datetime_mock.start()

    def test_need_test(self):
        self.datetime_mock.datetime.now().__sub__().total_seconds.return_value = 123
        self.assertEqual(need_test(), 123)
```

First of all `mock.patch(__name__ + ".datetime")` should be changed on `mock.patch.object(module.where.is.your.function, "datetime")`. And after that `self.datetime_mock.datetime.now()` (maybe) could be replaced with `self.datetime_mock.now()`

This example is not a propper way to do such testing, but it could resolve your question.